# How to find these data from my Revit Model ? (FORGE_MODEL_URN) , (FORGE_MODEL_VIEW), (DEVICE_MODEL_ID )

Tags: visual-studio, autodesk-forge, sensors, revit-api, urn

for starting most projects with Autodesk Forge, I need these data to use in coding. How can I get this information from my model?
(FORGE_MODEL_URN) ?
(FORGE_MODEL_VIEW) ?
(DEVICE_MODEL_ID) ?

[FORGE_MODEL_URN and FORGE_MODEL_VIEW (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75TDs.png)

[DEVICE_MODEL_ID (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Kmj.png)

Answer (score 0):

When building an Autodesk Platform Services (formerly Autodesk Forge) app, usually you just need to pass two env. variables to the app: the client ID (e.g., `FORGE_CLIENT_ID`) and client secret (e.g., `FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET`). The environment variables you mentioned are not typical at all. They are likely specific to just one specific sample app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
these variable are used in extension IoT and sensors. I am working on the package (Forge_IoT_Extension_demo_master). Do you mean, should I have these variables for my model or not?

(constFORGE_MODEL_URN='dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cGV0cmJyb3otc2FtcGxlcy9yYWNfYmFzaWNfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3RfMjAyMC5ydnQ';

const FORGE_MODEL_VIEW = 'e4baebbb-4ad6-8223-7f6a-cad4f0bb353a';)

 

"deviceModelId": "d370a293-4bd5-4bdb-a3df-376dc131d44c",
        "deviceInfo": [
            {
    "id": "Sensor_Plate [895520]-1",

Comment: You will need to ask the author of the "Forge_IoT_Extension_demo_master" package, perhaps submit an issue on their GitHub repo?

Comment: this package exactly (Forge_IoT_Extension_demo_master) is for you (petr broz ).
https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-iot-extensions-demo
I am so grateful, you reply me. I will connect on GitHub.